# open terminal option is not showing in all folders in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal

I have recently updated my Ubuntu before updated the open terminal option is appearing after update it is not appearing. I have seen many thing but yet cant find anything. Please help me how my open terminal appeared in all folders.

[image]

Comment: I have tried but not solved